# Complex CakePHP query refactoring

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp, model

I have just inherited a project and I need to re-work a bit of code so that the pagination of an infinite scroller still work properly.

Right now the code is grabbing all of the categories and their products, and listings.  I need to edit it so that only categories that have, products, which have active listings are returned.

Here is the code that eventually worked:

```
   $catData = $this->find('all',array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Indexer.type' => 'Category',
                'Listing.listing_id IS NOT NULL'
            ),
            'joins' => array(
                array('table' => 'peeka_product_category_link',
                    'alias' => 'Link',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Link.category_id = Category.category_id'
                    )
                ),
                array('table' => 'peeka_products',
                    'alias' => 'Product',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Product.product_id = Link.product_id'
                    )
                ),
                array('table' => 'peeka_listings',
                    'alias' => 'Listing',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Listing.product_id = Product.product_id',
                        'Listing.listing_end_date >=' => $date, 
                        'Listing.listing_start_date <=' => $date,
                        "Listing.listing_status = 'Active'"
                    )
                ),
            ),
            'order' => 'Category.category_name ASC',
            'limit' => $set_limit,
            'fields' => array('Category.category_id, Category.category_name, Indexer.url'),
            'group' => 'Category.category_id',
            'recursive' => 0
        ));
```

**EDIT:** Thanks to Dave this is working now and I just wanted to post it for future reference.  Maybe it will help someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "...only categories that have, products, which have active listings are
>   returned."
>
> "...a way to combine these three queries into one, so that the first
>   Category->find() function retrieves all the valid data."

To retrieve data and restrict it based on fields of associated models, you'll want to use [CakePHP's JOIN](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables).

It's hard to answer your question further than that without just writing the code for you, so - give JOINs a try, then come back and ask another more specific question if you have any issues with it.

Comment: I have added some joins and it's seems to be working.  Now is there a way to select distinct so that only one instance of the Category is returned?

Comment: @whatshakin - try using `GROUP BY` (or in Cake, it's "group").